# How to remove trailing newline after loop in Jinja2 template

Tags: jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template which contains a for loop. I would like each item in the for loop to be separated by a newline (including a newline before the first item). However, I have been unable to achieve this without an extra newline appearing after the loop.

```
{% set proxy_interfaces = {"Vlan2000": ["fc02:1000::/64"], "Vlan3000": ["fc03:1000::/64"]} %}
{%      for intf, prefix_list in proxy_interfaces.items() %}
{%          if prefix_list %}

proxy {{ name }} {
{%              for prefix in prefix_list %}
    prefix {{ prefix }} {
        static
    }
{%              endfor %}
}
{%          endif %}
{%      endfor %}
```

The actual output is

```
<newline>
proxy  {
    prefix fc03:1000::/64 {
        static
    }
}

proxy  {
    prefix fc02:1000::/64 {
        static
    }
}
<newline>
```

My desired output is:

```
<newline>
proxy  {
    prefix fc03:1000::/64 {
        static
    }
}

proxy  {
    prefix fc02:1000::/64 {
        static
    }
}
```

I've tried adding whitespace control characters `-` and `+` to different positions at the start and end of the loop and if tags, but have been unable to achieve the desired output. Unfortunately editing the Jinja environment to change `trim_blocks` and other parameters is not possible with my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the jinja docs for "white space control".
Lots of docs about this subject.

**Easy start which will solve most of your problems.**
I recommend to start all your jinja opening tags with `{%-`  <== with a dash

So something like this:

```
<div>
    {%- if True %}
        yay
    {%-  endif %}
</div>
```

will be rendered like this: (without blank lines above and under the: yay)

```
<div>
        yay
</div>
```